# Pcap functions have "undefined reference"

Tags: c, linux, pcap, undefined-reference, libpcap

I'm trying to go through this tutorial:
http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html

Now I have install pcap (code hints and all that is working) using :

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

and so far I have the following code (file name is example_pcap.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *dev, errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);

    return 0;
}
```

According to many questions I have seen already they said to compile it using this:

```
gcc -lpcap example_pcap.c -o example_pcap
```

However I still get the following error:

```
example_pcap.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `pcap_lookupdev'
```

Comment: @NTN 1. linker errors are usually unrelated to header files, and 2. the error message is **not** "library not found". The issue is that the library is in the wrong place – it should be *after* the source file.

Comment: Ohh yes, you could use -L/your/path/ to add new path to locate lib

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Move `-lpcap` to the end of the command line

See [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)

Comment: As in `gcc example_pcap.c -o example_pcap -lpcap` (I added -o to get an executable with a better name than `a.out`)

Comment: This worked but now I'm a little confused. As part of my coursework they have already given me the make file. Now the make file has the -lpcap parameter BEFORE the rest. Did they make a mistake, or is there a way to make sure it stays at the start?

Comment: linking ../build/idsniff
gcc -lpcap -lpthread -o ../build/idsniff ../build/analysis.o ../build/dispatch.o ../build/main.o ../build/sniff.o
../build/sniff.o: In function `sniff':
/home/yahya/workspace/osCoursework/src/sniff.c:15: undefined reference to `pcap_open_live'
/home/yahya/workspace/osCoursework/src/sniff.c:27: undefined reference to `pcap_next'
/home/yahya/workspace/osCoursework/src/sniff.c:31: undefined reference to `pcap_geterr'

Comment: @YahyaUddin yes they made a mistake. It's possible that on the particular system they used back when they wrote the course material, it happened to work.