# aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcap

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, pcap, libpcap, lpc

I had the same isue in this problem [Pcap functions have "undefined reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107998/pcap-functions-have-undefined-reference)  and this code line solved it.
 `gcc  expl1.c -lpcap`
But now I am trying to cross-compile the same file using this command
`aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a57 expl1.c -lpcap`
but I got this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcap
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Are you crosscompiling? Did you install pcap __compiled for aarch64-linux-gnu__ ?

Comment: I did solve my problem. I croos compiled libpcap for aarch64